# I want to know this code base on ORM or ODM?

Tags: flutter, dart, orm, nosql, odm

I want to ask you about this code is ORM base or ODM base?
I use Firebase (NoSQL)
Programming Language is Dart and Flutter.

```
Future _uploadFile(BuildContext context) async {
final firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child('post')
    .child('${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png');

final task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(
  _image,
  StorageMetadata(contentType: 'image/png'),
);

final storageTaskSnapshot = await task.onComplete;

final downloadUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

await Firestore.instance.collection('post').add(
    {
      'contents': textEditingController.text,
      'displayName': widget.user.displayName,
      'email': widget.user.email,
      'photoUrl': downloadUrl,
      'userPhotoUrl': widget.user.photoUrl,
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **ODM** maps between an object model and a document database, and **Firebase Storage** collects data as a document.

So, it would be considered an **ODM** base.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can understand why "Firebase Storage" is ODM base :)